# Weird width reported in DOM (0, when element has width)

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I think the image explains what's going on pretty well.  I know this happens with images that haven't loaded yet.. and the width of this element *is* changing, but the functions I need the width with are being called and extracting the width afterwards, and usually Web Inspector updates itself, so... what could be happening here? (I'm trying to apply the width of one element to another, and because of the 0 reported width the second element is invisible.  It's only doing this on some of the elements, though.

These are inline elements, so perhaps that's the reason? But clearly someone is generating a width somewhere, and it is working with other inline elements with the same js but different css.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a live link we could see? Did you also notice that the height is reported as `0`?

Comment: What happens if you expand width?

Comment: @pimvdb of the browser? or the element itself? I can't apply width to it directly bc it's inline.

Comment: @Matt height is 0 as well, yeah. It's not deployed yet so unfortunately can't give a link

Comment: @Damon: I mean that little arrow on the right of your screenshot.

Comment: Right now it told me the 100px width I'd given it forgetting that it was an inline element and couldn't use width. I just noticed on the stylesheet where it is working the links are specified as 'block', and it works when I do that.

Comment: What code do you use to get the width? offsetWidth? For inline element you might want to try getBoundingClientRect().

Comment: I'm using a function I found on SO that grabs all the style elements from an element (i'm making an input look like the element it's replacing. (essentially replicating content-editable for use on iOS argh). I think I'll just keep everything as inline and it will work. Assuming that odd looking behaviour in the inspector is just how inline elements work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elements with "display: inline" such as `<span>`'s or `<a>`'s do not use or have a width style property. If you set the element to "display: inline-block" it will use a width style property.

element.offsetWidth will give you a proper width, but the "computed style" of a inline element will always be 0. Inline elements have an automatic width, so the style applied has no effect.